# Page Not Found Old CSS References

Tags: theming

Recently, we did a complete overhaul of our theme. We have been working with a subtheme of Zen. We are still working with one, but we made it from scratch. Though it is now in place, we are receiving "Page Not Found" errors with calls to the old css files. Has anyone experienced this before, where could they be getting called from?

I've checked to make sure no css file is importing them and no info file is calling them.

Comment: Did you clear the caches?

Comment: Yes, I've cleared the caches hundreds of times since the launch two weeks ago.

Comment: Very strange; nothing really comes to my mind. Did you try scanning the theme for those filenames, just in case they are left somewhere? CSS could have been added through other places (e.g. `hook_preprocess_X`).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. We're not using any pre or post processing hooks. I've also done a search though all the theme files and nothing has come up as reference to the old css files. There are (empty) scss files by the same name, but I don't think they have anything do with this problem. I've also done searches on our database to see if there were hard-coded calls to those files but nothing has turned up.

Comment: Try replicating this on a clean install; if it works there, I'd make a clone of the site and remove sections/modules one by one and checking what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a search of the entire codebase (not just theme files), as well as a database search in all tables (it should only take about 3 minutes).

**UPDATE:**

Also, make sure you have taken any content delivery network (CDN) caching into account. Are these files causing "File-not-found" errors from a remote browser, or from a browser on the local machine (dev laptop, for instance).

If you do have a CDN in place (MaxCDN, CloudFront, Akamai, etc.) you can try uploading a mostly blank CSS file with the same name as the one that you're attempting to get rid of.

Comment: That's a good idea. I searched the whole database with various snippets of the files being called and the only place they appeared was in the log files to say that there was a page not found error.